# (Discrete math) Prove sets

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Can someone help me prove that: $$((A \cap B)  \oplus  A)' = A' \cup B$$

$A'$ is $A$ complement.

Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I started with the left side and was using set identities and that only proved A' $\cup$ $\emptyset$. I don't know what to do differently.

Comment: what is $\oplus$?

Comment: $\oplus$ is all elements in A or B, but not in both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> $$p⊕q\equiv (p\land\neg q)\lor (\neg p\land q)\equiv(p\lor q)\land(\neg p\lor\neg q)\tag*{aka Xor}$$

This set notation '$⊕$' corresponding to xor in logic.

Any $x\in ((A\cap B)⊕A)'$ if and only if:$$\neg((x\in A\land x\in B)⊕x\in A)$$
Since $\neg((p\land q)⊕ p)\leftrightarrow(\neg p\lor q)$ is a tautology,
It's clearly equivalent to $x\not\in A\lor x\in B$, hence proved$\dots$
But if you can't say this, here is a proof with [Logical equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_equivalence):

Apply def. of Xor:

$$\neg(((x\in A\land x\in B)\land x\not\in A)\lor(\neg(x\in A\land x\in B)\land x\in A))$$

Apply Commutative law & Associative law:

$$\neg(((x\in A\land x\not\in A)\land x\in B)\lor(\neg(x\in A\land x\in B)\land x\in A))$$

Apply Negation law:

$$\neg((\bot\land x\in B)\lor(\neg(x\in A\land x\in B)\land x\in A))$$

Apply Domination law:

$$\neg(\bot\lor(\neg(x\in A\land x\in B)\land x\in A))$$

Apply Identity law:

$$\neg(\neg(x\in A\land x\in B)\land x\in A)$$

Apply De Morgan's law:

$$\neg((x\not\in A\lor x\not\in B)\land x\in A)$$

Apply Distributive law:

$$\neg((x\not\in A\land x\in A)\lor (x\not\in B\land x\in A))$$

Apply Negation law:

$$\neg(\bot\lor (x\not\in B\land x\in A))$$

Apply Domination law:

$$\neg(x\not\in B\land x\in A)$$

Apply De Morgan's law:

$$x\in B\lor x\not\in A$$

Apply Commutative law:

$$x\not\in A\lor x\in B$$

This hold if and only if $x\in A'\cup B$

Hence we proved $((A\cap B)⊕A)'=A'\cup B\tag*{$\square$}$

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\oplus$ denotes the **symmetric difference** between two sets. In other words,

> $$P \oplus Q = (P-Q) \cup (Q-P) = (P  \cap Q') \cup (Q \cap P')$$

**Using this definition as well as set identities, we have the following proof:**

$ \big( (A \cap B) \oplus A \big)' $

$= \bigg[ \big( (A \cap B) \cap A' \big) \cup \big( A \cap (A \cap B)' \big) \bigg]' $ ----- by definition of $\oplus$

$= \bigg[ \big( (B \cap A) \cap A' \big) \cup \big( A \cap (A \cap B)' \big) \bigg]' $ ----- by the commutative law

$= \bigg[ \big( B \cap (A \cap A') \big) \cup \big( A \cap (A \cap B)' \big) \bigg]' $ ----- by the associative law

$= \bigg[ ( B \cap \emptyset ) \cup \big( A \cap (A \cap B)' \big) \bigg]' $ ----- by the complement law

$= \bigg[ \emptyset \cup \big( A \cap (A \cap B)' \big) \bigg]' $ ----- by the domination law

$= \bigg[ A \cap (A \cap B)' \bigg]' $ ----- by the identity law

$= A' \cup (A \cap B)'' $ ----- by DeMorgan's law

$= A' \cup (A \cap B) $ ----- by the double complement law

$= (A' \cup A) \cap (A' \cup B) $ ----- by the distributive law

$= U \cap (A' \cup B) $ ----- by the complement law

$= A' \cup B $ ----- by the identity law

**NOTE:** As @Manx has noted, you may also use the definitions of various set operations to expand these statements about sets and then apply the rules of inference. For simplicity, I chose to preserve the set notation and utilize set identities, which I assume you are familiar with.